# Accept SDK Bad Excess Crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, exc-bad-access

I am using accept SDK for iOS in my project and its crashing with EXC_BAD_ACCESS

```
AcceptSDKHandler *handler = [[AcceptSDKHandler alloc] initWithEnvironment:AcceptSDKEnvironmentENV_TEST];
    AcceptSDKRequest *request = [[AcceptSDKRequest alloc] init];
    request.merchantAuthentication.name = @""; //name
    request.merchantAuthentication.clientKey = @""; //clientkey

    request.securePaymentContainerRequest.webCheckOutDataType.token.cardNumber = @""; //cardnumber
    request.securePaymentContainerRequest.webCheckOutDataType.token.expirationMonth = @"";
    request.securePaymentContainerRequest.webCheckOutDataType.token.expirationYear = @"";
    request.securePaymentContainerRequest.webCheckOutDataType.token.cardCode = @"";
   //crashing on below line
    **[handler getTokenWithRequest:request successHandler:^(AcceptSDKTokenResponse * _Nonnull token)** {
        NSLog(@"success %@", token.getOpaqueData.getDataValue);
    } failureHandler:^(AcceptSDKErrorResponse * _Nonnull error) {
        NSLog(@"failed... );
    }];
```

Comment: Is there any error message in console? Is ` NSLog(@"success %@", token.getOpaqueData.getDataValue);` crashing or the `getTokenWithRequest:successHandler:failureHandler:`?

Comment: getTokenWithRequest:successHandler:failureHandler is crashing...its not entering inside the block...If i comment NSLOG it still crash

Comment: Is there any error message in console?

Comment: No there is no error message , it stops at that line with EXC_BAD_ACCESS